# php - get html table from url - td have nested elements

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I have a URL that contain the table like the following

```
<table id='table1'>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <div class='us'>
     </div>
    </td>
    <td>
     <div>
      <span>text1</span>
     </div>
    </td>
    <td>
     <span>text2</span>
    </td>
    <td>text3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <div class='jo'></div>
    </td>
    <td>
     <div>
      <span>text4</span>
     </div>
    </td>
    <td>
     <span>text5</span>
    </td>
    <td>text6</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

i want to get the data from table like this using php

```
us - text1 - text2 - text3
jo - text4 - text5 - text6
```

i can get the data if td has no children elements the problem occur when there is children for td like div inside td 
notice also that in column 1 i need the class inside div inside td

so basically i need a code that loop through table rows in first column i need the class of the div inside td , in second column i need the text inside span inside div inside td, in third column i need text inside span inside td in 4th column i just need the text inside td, currently the only column i can get is the 4th column because the text is directly inside the td

any idea?

Comment: You have provided the answer in your tags.

Comment: yes but the problem is with nested childs of td, i can loop through td and get the text inside td how i can get the text inside div inside td while looping.

Comment: notice also that in the first column i need the class of the div inside td

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: i want to get all the content of the table i can get the text inside td directly but the problem occur when there is a div inside td i need the text inside that div but when i loop the text not appear.

Comment: what you want to retrieve ? you also need class name for div ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the HTML into a [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), then fetch the requested values using [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) [queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/):

```
$html = <<<EOS
<table id='table1'>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <div class='us'>
     </div>
    </td>
    <td>
     <div>
      <span>text1</span>
     </div>
    </td>
    <td>
     <span>text2</span>
    </td>
    <td>text3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <div class='jo'></div>
    </td>
    <td>
     <div>
      <span>text4</span>
     </div>
    </td>
    <td>
     <span>text5</span>
    </td>
    <td>text6</td>
   </tr>
</table>
EOS;

// Load HTML into a DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

// Find div's with class attribute
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divsWithClassAttribute = $xPath->query('//div[@class]');

// Loop through divs
foreach ($divsWithClassAttribute as $div) {
    // Create row array starting with class name
    $row = array($div->getAttribute('class'));

    // Get siblings of the td parent of each div
    $siblings = $xPath->query('parent::td/following-sibling::td', $div);

    // Loop through (td) siblings and extract text content
    foreach ($siblings as $sibling) {
        $row[] = trim($sibling->textContent); // Add text value
    }

    // Output row
    echo implode(' - ', $row), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
us - text1 - text2 - text3
jo - text4 - text5 - text6
```